# I want to bring the height of each text box in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm asking for advice.
On the page I'm working on, there are several 'Div' and there are 'text boxes' and 'background pictures' in them.

I want to bring the height of each text box in the page.
The height of the box varies depending on the amount of text.
Each text box height value is used as the margin value of the 'background pictures'.

but, It seems that the current code is only bringing in the code of one specific text box.

http://client.1-2-3-4-5.studio/ppeaches/

```js
var myHeight = $(".text-box").innerHeight() + 'px'; 

$(".bg").attr("style", 'margin-top: -' + myHeight + ";");

console.log(myHeight);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.demo {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.demo.box-one {
    background: grey;
}

.demo.box-two {
    background: beige;
}

.demo.box-three {
    background: blue;
}

.demo.box-four {
    background: pink;
}

.demo.box-five {
    background: orange;
}

.demo.box-six {
    background: green;
}


.offset {
  height: 500px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.top {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.top .text-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 3vw;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 99;
    display: block;
    margin-top: var(--height);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.text-box {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 3vw;
    font-size: 10vw;
    line-height: 11vw;
    margin-bottom: -2vw;
    z-index: 9999999;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.stick {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="boxset">
    <div class="demo" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Danh Vo
      Selected Bibliograph
    2007 – 2015</span>
      <span class="bg"><img src="http://archiv11.org/WordPress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/00-DANH-VO-Biblio-IMG_2109-w1200.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-one" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Installation view of Danh Vo
      Uuntitled at the South London Gallery, 2019.</span>
      <span class="bg"><img src="https://artmap.com/static/media/0000129000/0000128091.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-two" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Blauorange 2007</span>
      <span class="bg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-three" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Danh Vo
      Selected Bibliograph
    2007 – 2015</span>
      <span class="bg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-four" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Félix González-Torres
      "Untitled" (Portrait of Julie Ault)</span>
      <span class="bg>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-five" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo box-six" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo box-seven" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://sommm.kr/onetwothreefourfive/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://sommm.kr/onetwothreefourfive/js/ajax/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://sommm.kr/onetwothreefourfive/js/jquery.hypher.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://sommm.kr/onetwothreefourfive/js/en-us.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.5/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following problems in your code:

1. You're trying to get the height value of all elements in `$(".text-box")` without iterating over it;
2. You're trying to use an inexistent `innerHeight()` function for those elements;
3. The same thing pointed out in the first item is happening when you try to set an attribute for the elements in `$(".bg")`.

It looks like you really need to understand JavaScript fundamentals better.

In the code below, I iterate through the textboxes and gather the height value of each one of them inside an array. To get the values, I use the function `getBoundingClientRect()`. Then, I iterate through the newly created array to set the `margin-top` style for each `.bg` element, by means of the jQuery `css()` function.

```js
var textboxesHeight = $(".text-box").get().map(textbox => {
  return textbox.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
});

textboxesHeight.forEach((val, i) => {
  $(".bg").eq(i).css("margin-top", '-' + val);
  console.log(val);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.demo {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.demo.box-one {
    background: grey;
}

.demo.box-two {
    background: beige;
}

.demo.box-three {
    background: blue;
}

.demo.box-four {
    background: pink;
}

.demo.box-five {
    background: orange;
}

.demo.box-six {
    background: green;
}


.offset {
  height: 500px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.top {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.top .text-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 3vw;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 99;
    display: block;
    margin-top: var(--height);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.text-box {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 3vw;
    font-size: 10vw;
    line-height: 11vw;
    margin-bottom: -2vw;
    z-index: 9999999;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.stick {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="boxset">
    <div class="demo" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Danh Vo
      Selected Bibliograph
    2007 – 2015</span>
      <span class="bg"><img src="http://archiv11.org/WordPress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/00-DANH-VO-Biblio-IMG_2109-w1200.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-one" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Installation view of Danh Vo
      Uuntitled at the South London Gallery, 2019.</span>
      <span class="bg"><img src="https://artmap.com/static/media/0000129000/0000128091.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-two" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Blauorange 2007</span>
      <span class="bg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-three" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Danh Vo
      Selected Bibliograph
    2007 – 2015</span>
      <span class="bg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-four" touching="top">
      <span class="text-box">Félix González-Torres
      "Untitled" (Portrait of Julie Ault)</span>
      <span class="bg>
    </div>
    <div class="demo box-five" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo box-six" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo box-seven" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="top"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="green"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="black"></div>
    <div class="demo" touching="orange"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://sommm.kr/onetwothreefourfive/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://sommm.kr/onetwothreefourfive/js/ajax/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://sommm.kr/onetwothreefourfive/js/jquery.hypher.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://sommm.kr/onetwothreefourfive/js/en-us.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.5/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm studying... Your advice was helpful to me. I'll read it carefully and study. Thank you.